# Get data from MySQL database filtered by date with Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring

I have table take_coffee and I want to filter data by date. I need to get data from last week, month and a year. Data are about taken coffee, so it has an id, date and tag. How could I do the filtering? I need something like query with WHERE date > (today-7), or today-30 or today-365.
Thanks.
Here is my code, but it's not working properly.
Entity

```
 @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "take_coffee")
    public class Coffee {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date date;
        private String tag;

    }
```

Repository

```
public interface CoffeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Coffee, Integer> {
    List<Coffee> findAllByDateBetween(Date today, Date days);
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class CoffeeService {

    @Autowired
    private CoffeeRepository repository;


    public Coffee takeCoffee(Coffee coffee){
        return repository.save(coffee);
    }

    public List<Coffee> getAllCoffee(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Coffee getCoffeeById(int id){
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public String deleteCoffeeById(int id){
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return "deleted coffee " + id;
    }

    public Coffee updateCoffee(Coffee coffee){
        Coffee existingcoffee = repository.findById(coffee.getId()).orElse(null);
        existingcoffee.setDate(coffee.getDate());
        existingcoffee.setTag(coffee.getTag());
        return repository.save(existingcoffee);
    }

    public List<Coffee> findAllByDateBetween(int days){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = calendar.getTime();

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -days);
        Date beforeDays = calendar.getTime();
        return repository.findAllByDateBetween(today, beforeDays);
    }
}
```

Controller -cross origin cause of ReactApp

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class CoffeeController {

    @Autowired
    private CoffeeService service;

    @PostMapping("/takeCoffee")
    public Coffee takeCaffee (@RequestBody Coffee caffee){
        return service.takeCoffee(caffee);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getCoffee")
    public List<Coffee> getAllUsers(){
        return service.getAllCoffee();
    }

    @GetMapping("/coffee/{id}")
    public Coffee getCaffeeById(@PathVariable int id){
        return service.getCoffeeById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/coffee/stats/{days}")
    public List<Coffee> findAllByDateBetween(@PathVariable int days){
        return service.findAllByDateBetween(days);
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateCoffee")
    public Coffee updateCoffee (@RequestBody Coffee caffee){
        return service.updateCoffee(caffee);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/deleteCoffee/{id}")
    public String deleteCoffeeById (@PathVariable int id){
        return service.deleteCoffeeById(id);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just swap the parameters `today` and `beforeDays` to be like

```
return repository.findAllByDateBetween(beforeDays, today);
```

Because beforeDays < today according to your calculation, and the earlier date should be passed first to `between`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain to me, how to get count of rows? I need to get result like 'It was taken 30 coffees last month'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your method name seems incorrect. If my mind is working right now, you should have:

```
List<Coffee> findAllByDateLessThanAndDateGreaterThan(Date today, Date days);
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. I solved it by changing the order of input parameters.